# OrientDB - Can't access on my DB about schema fault

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I've a superclass named `BaseData` and a derived class `MyData`.

At the start, I've added on my `MyData` class a property named `period`.

After this, by studio, I've added on my `BaseData` the same property named `period`.

After this. I've restarted my server and by that moment I can't access on my Orient DB server with this error:

> Error: com.orientechnologies.common.exception.OException: Error on creation of shared resource
>
> Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSchemaException: Cannot add base class 'MyData', because of parameter conflict: period (
> type=INTEGER) vs period (type=INTEGER)

I've tried to access via console but I've the same result, so I can't drop property and I can't use my DB.

Comment: Which version of OrientDb are you using ?

Comment: More precisely 2.1.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried your schema on 2.1.4 community version and I have the same identical error as yours.

Than I have tried the same schema on 2.1.18 community without any problems.
Can You, please, try with the latest community version and let me know?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok, I try your recommended version and then I'll communicate the result. Thanks in advance